# Can someone break this anonymous function down and explain?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
n => +n && [...1e9+''].map(_ => n += 9);
```

This prints an array of numbers that 'n' is a digital root for. I would like to know how this is done through this function given above?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: AND operator, spread operator, and fat arrow syntax

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: What is a "digital root"?

Comment: Try pasting this code inside http://babeljs.io/

Comment: Digital Root is for example  you have the number , 523 , the digital root is 1 , 5+2+3 = 10 , 1+0 = 1 . You keep adding the numbers amongst themselves until you reach a single number

Comment: I understand all the components in the code , but i would like to know how does it compute the answer to return the array of numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it down one step at a time as follows:

```
n => +n && [...1e9+''].map(_ => n += 9);

n => +n && [...1000000000+''].map(_ => n += 9);

n => +n && ['1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'].map(_ => n += 9);

n => +n && [n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9,n += 9];

n => +n && [n+9, n+18, n+27, n+36, n+45, n+54, n+63, n+72, n+81, n+90];
```

The confusing thing here is the `[...1e9+'']`, which is nothing but a confusing way to create an array with ten elements, taking advantage of the fact that the spread notation `...` transforms a string into an array of individual code points. It would be clearer to write `Array.from({length: 10})`, in which case you could use the second parameter and not use `map` at all, as in `Array.from({length: 10}, (v, i) => n + 9*(i+1))`.

Comment: actually if you add those array of numbers between themselves you get the digital root which is n

Answer (score 7):

Lets see...

1. `+n` - converts the input into a number
2. `&&` - if `+n` is not `0` or `NaN` ot another falsy value the function proceeds otherwise returns this falsy value
3. `1e9+''` - converts this number to a string: `"1000000000"`
4. `[..."1000000000"]` - uses the new 'spread' operator to populate the array with the digits => `["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`
5. `.map(_=>n+=9)` - replaces each digit in the array with `n+9` and increases the value of `n` with `9` for the next item

So for `n = 1` you end up with: `[10, 19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 91]`